# I can't connect storybook/testing-vue 3 to my project

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, vuejs3, storybook

I executed the command:
`npm install --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps @storybook/testing-vue3`
Then I connect the library:
`import { composeStories } from '@storybook/testing-vue3'`
I run my test and get this error:

```
Cannot find module '@storybook/client-logger' from 'node_modules/@storybook/testing-vue3/dist/testing-vue3.cjs.development.js'

    Require stack:
      node_modules/@storybook/testing-vue3/dist/testing-vue3.cjs.development.js
      node_modules/@storybook/testing-vue3/dist/index.js
      tests/unit/modal.spec.js

      4 | import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/vue'
      5 | import { Default } from '@/components/modal/modal.stories'
    > 6 | import { composeStories } from '@storybook/testing-vue3'
        | ^
      7 |
      8 | it('showCloser render test', async () => {
      9 |     const wrapper = mount(modal, {
```

My jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'json', 'vue'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
    "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest",
    "\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/svgTransform.js",
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['/src/**/*.vue'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  },
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src', __dirname],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    customExportConditions: ["node", "node-addons"],
 },
}
```

I'm a beginner and I haven't found any tips on the Internet, so I hope for your help